# Behaviour of Lag function in scala when the column is null

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am applying the `lag` function over a column in my dataframe. The column which the `lag` function is applied on already contains some null values. How to exclude computing the `lag` on the rows which have a null value?

Below is the data from dataframe:

```
+------------+-------------+-----+-----+
| NUM_ID     | TIME        |SG1_V|SG2_V|
+------------+-------------+-----+-----+
|XXXXX01     |1570167499000|     |79.0 |
|XXXXX01     |1570167502000|     |88.0 |
|XXXXX01     |1570167503000|80.0 |99.0 |
|XXXXX01     |1570179810000|81.0 |     |
|XXXXX01     |1570179811000|92.0 |     |
+------------+-------------+-----+-----+
```

I wrote a `lag` function as below to get the previous row value along with the current value:

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("NUM_ID").orderBy("TIME")  
val leadDF = df2.withColumn("PREVIOUS_SG1", lag("SG1_V", 1, 0).over(w)).withColumn("PREVIOUS_SG2", lag("SG2_V", 1, 0).over(w))
```

I am getting the below output:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+------+
| NUM_ID     | TIME        |PREVIOUS_SG1|SG1_V|PREVIOUS_SG2|SG2_V |
+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+------+
|XXXXX01     |1570167499000|            |     |     0      |99.0  |
|XXXXX01     |1570167502000|    0       | 78.0|  99.0      |      |
|XXXXX01     |1570167503000|    78.0    |     |            |85.0  |
|XXXXX01     |1570179810000|            |81.0 |  85.0      |81.0  |
|XXXXX01     |1570179811000|    81.0    |92.0 |  81.0      |      |
|XXXXX01     |1570179833000|    92.0    |     |            |77.0  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here in the output for the column `SIG1_V` and `SIG2_V` which are having null/no value is also getting value in previous SIG value. Is there any way to exclude the lag whenever the `SIG1_V` and `SIG2_V` columns are null/no value?

Expected output is as shown below.

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+------+
| NUM_ID     | TIME        |PREVIOUS_SG1|SG1_V|PREVIOUS_SG2|SG2_V |
+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+------+
|XXXXX01     |1570167499000|            |     |     0      |99.0  |
|XXXXX01     |1570167502000|    0       | 78.0|            |      |
|XXXXX01     |1570167503000|            |     |            |85.0  |
|XXXXX01     |1570179810000|            |81.0 |  85.0      |81.0  |
|XXXXX01     |1570179811000|    81.0    |92.0 |            |      |
|XXXXX01     |1570179833000|            |     |            |77.0  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible? Appreciate any leads!

Comment: try this it will get you, your  desire output 
var  leadDF= df2.withColumn("PREVIOUS_SG1", when($"SG1_V".isNull,"").otherwise(lag("SG1_V", 1, 0).over(w))).withColumn("PREVIOUS_SG2",when($"SG2_V".isNull,"").otherwise(lag("SG2_V", 1, 0).over(w))).show

Answer (score 1):

Remove the values you don't want after computing the lags instead of trying to exlude them during the computation. This can be done by setting the values of the lag columns to null whenever the original column is null:

```
leadDF.withColumn("PREVIOUS_SG1", when($"SG1_V".isNull, $"SG1_V").otherwise($"PREVIOUS_SG1"))
  .withColumn("PREVIOUS_SG2", when($"SG2_V".isNull, $"SG2_V").otherwise($"PREVIOUS_SG2"))
```